# print ("Hello World") in swift showing as "Hello World\n"

Tags: swift, swift2

I have just started out in swift and i have been practising it for awhile. But often when i am printing a statement such as "Hello World" in the playground, it shows it as "Hello World\n". I am not sure why. Please do help me out with this.
This is my very own question. I couldn't find answers and so I decided to ask out in the community.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant source code from your program.

Comment: This is on the right side of the playground, correct?  That's where it shows you things being evaluated.  To see the actual output, open up the bottom view.

Comment: "\n" show you that the next output would be in the new line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` function

```
print("Hello world")
```

does print the value it receives as param + a new line character `\n`.

```
"Hello world" + "\n" -> "Hello world\n"
```

If you don't want the `\n` at the end you can tell the print function to omit it

```
print("Hello world", terminator: "")
```